# Marklogic Xquery fn:data(<type>hello world</type>) giving Invalid lexical value error

Tags: xquery, marklogic

My Marklogic XQuery  `fn:data(<type>hello world</type>)` gives me **Invalid lexical value error**

This is the stack trace:

```
query evaluated in Documents at file::Docs/ as 1.0-ml (cq v4.1-1-EA)

[1.0-ml] XDMP-LEXVAL: xs:integer("hello world") -- Invalid lexical value "hello world"
Stack trace:

line 2:
1: 
2: fn:data(<type>hello world</type>)

xdmp:eval("&#13;&#10;fn:data(<type>hello world</type>)", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation></options>)


in /cq/eval.xqy line 111:
```

And when I use `fn:data(<p>hello world</p>)` it is giving me expected answer (hello world).

Any help on this error would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured what was wrong.
Had an xsd which was defining element `type` as `xs:integer` thats why this error was coming. Removed that xsd and now everything is working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Glad you figured it out. It looks like the extra schema was targeting the empty namespace?

Here's a tip: avoid using a schema unless it also specifies a namespace. That makes it much easier to keep your schemas organized.